# How do I remove optional text from UILabel

Tags: ios, json, swift, struct

I'm trying to remove the `Optional` text on my `UILabel` when I run the app. However, I already tried many ways and the `Optional` persists.

It's important to say that I got these values from `JSON`, so I created a `Struct` to decode all this Data. The property `ibu` is the only one that has `Optional` written, but if I remove the `?` I got an error on `JSONDecoder` that say's:

> Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index
>   23", intValue: 23), CodingKeys(stringValue: "ibu", intValue: nil)],
>   debugDescription: "Expected Double value but found null instead.",
>   underlyingError: nil))

How do I fix that?

***App Picture:***
[image]

***Model Folder:***

```
  struct Cerveja:Decodable{
        let name:String
        let image_url:String
        let description:String
        let tagline:String
        let abv:Double
        let ibu:Double? //This one that I got the "Optional" written in the UILabel
                        //If I remove the "?" I got the error below
    }
```

***View Folder - Details Screen:***

```
var item:Cerveja?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    labelName.text = item?.name
    labelDescricao.text = item?.description
    labelAmargor.text = "\(String(describing: item!.ibu))" 
    labelTeorAlc.text = "\(item!.abv)"

    let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: URL(string: "\(item?.image_url ?? "")")!, cacheKey: item?.image_url)
    imageDetail.kf.setImage(with: resource)
}
```

***Networking Folder:***

```
func getApiData(completion: @escaping ([Cerveja]) -> ()){
    guard let urlString = URL(string: "https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers") else {
        print("URL Error")
        return
    }
    Alamofire.request(urlString).responseJSON { response in

        if response.data == response.data{
            do{
                let decoder = try JSONDecoder().decode([Cerveja].self, from: response.data!)

                completion(decoder)
            }catch{
        print(error)
            }
        }else{print("API Response is Empty")}

        }
}
```

***JSON:***

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Buzz",
    "tagline": "A Real Bitter Experience.",
    "first_brewed": "09\/2007",
    "description": "A light, crisp and bitter IPA brewed with English and American hops. A small batch brewed only once.",
    "image_url": "https:\/\/images.punkapi.com\/v2\/keg.png",
    "abv": 4.5,
    "ibu": 60,
    "target_fg": 1010,
    "target_og": 1044,
    "ebc": 20,
    "srm": 10,
    "ph": 4.4,
    "attenuation_level": 75,
    "volume": {
      "value": 20,
      "unit": "liters"
    },
    "boil_volume": {
      "value": 25,
      "unit": "liters"
    },
    "method": {
      "mash_temp": [
        {
          "temp": {
            "value": 64,
            "unit": "celsius"
          },
          "duration": 75
        }
      ],
      "fermentation": {
        "temp": {
          "value": 19,
          "unit": "celsius"
        }
      },
      "twist": null
    },
    "ingredients": {
      "malt": [
        {
          "name": "Maris Otter Extra Pale",
          "amount": {
            "value": 3.3,
            "unit": "kilograms"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Caramalt",
          "amount": {
            "value": 0.2,
            "unit": "kilograms"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Munich",
          "amount": {
            "value": 0.4,
            "unit": "kilograms"
          }
        }
      ],
      "hops": [
        {
          "name": "Fuggles",
          "amount": {
            "value": 25,
            "unit": "grams"
          },
          "add": "start",
          "attribute": "bitter"
        },
        {
          "name": "First Gold",
          "amount": {
            "value": 25,
            "unit": "grams"
          },
          "add": "start",
          "attribute": "bitter"
        },
        {
          "name": "Fuggles",
          "amount": {
            "value": 37.5,
            "unit": "grams"
          },
          "add": "middle",
          "attribute": "flavour"
        },
        {
          "name": "First Gold",
          "amount": {
            "value": 37.5,
            "unit": "grams"
          },
          "add": "middle",
          "attribute": "flavour"
        },
        {
          "name": "Cascade",
          "amount": {
            "value": 37.5,
            "unit": "grams"
          },
          "add": "end",
          "attribute": "flavour"
        }
      ],
      "yeast": "Wyeast 1056 - American Ale\u2122"
    },
    "food_pairing": [
      "Spicy chicken tikka masala",
      "Grilled chicken quesadilla",
      "Caramel toffee cake"
    ],
    "brewers_tips": "The earthy and floral aromas from the hops can be overpowering. Drop a little Cascade in at the end of the boil to lift the profile with a bit of citrus.",
    "contributed_by": "Sam Mason <samjbmason>"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Trashy Blonde",
    "tagline": "You Know You Shouldn't",
    "first_brewed": "04\/2008",
    "description": "A titillating, neurotic, peroxide punk of a Pale Ale. Combining attitude, style, substance, and a little bit of low self esteem for good measure; what would your mother say? The seductive lure of the sassy passion fruit hop proves too much to resist. All that is even before we get onto the fact that there are no additives, preservatives, pasteurization or strings attached. All wrapped up with the customary BrewDog bite and imaginative twist.",
    "image_url": "https:\/\/images.punkapi.com\/v2\/2.png",
    "abv": 4.1,
    "ibu": 41.5,
    "target_fg": 1010,
    "target_og": 1041.7,
    "ebc": 15,
    "srm": 15,
    "ph": 4.4,
    "attenuation_level": 76,
    "volume": {
      "value": 20,
      "unit": "liters"
    },
    "boil_volume": {
      "value": 25,
      "unit": "liters"
    },
    "method": {
      "mash_temp": [
        {
          "temp": {
            "value": 69,
            "unit": "celsius"
          },
          "duration": null
        }
      ],
      "fermentation": {
        "temp": {
          "value": 18,
          "unit": "celsius"
        }
      },
      "twist": null
    },
    "ingredients": {
      "malt": [
        {
          "name": "Maris Otter Extra Pale",
          "amount": {
            "value": 3.25,
            "unit": "kilograms"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Caramalt",
          "amount": {
            "value": 0.2,
            "unit": "kilograms"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Munich",
          "amount": {
            "value": 0.4,
            "unit": "kilograms"
          }
        }
      ],
      "hops": [
        {
          "name": "Amarillo",
          "amount": {
            "value": 13.8,
            "unit": "grams"
          },
          "add": "start",
          "attribute": "bitter"
        },
        {
          "name": "Simcoe",
          "amount": {
            "value": 13.8,
            "unit": "grams"
          },
          "add": "start",
          "attribute": "bitter"
        },
        {
          "name": "Amarillo",
          "amount": {
            "value": 26.3,
            "unit": "grams"
          },
          "add": "end",
          "attribute": "flavour"
        },
        {
          "name": "Motueka",
          "amount": {
            "value": 18.8,
            "unit": "grams"
          },
          "add": "end",
          "attribute": "flavour"
        }
      ],
      "yeast": "Wyeast 1056 - American Ale\u2122"
    },
    "food_pairing": [
      "Fresh crab with lemon",
      "Garlic butter dipping sauce",
      "Goats cheese salad",
      "Creamy lemon bar doused in powdered sugar"
    ],
    "brewers_tips": "Be careful not to collect too much wort from the mash. Once the sugars are all washed out there are some very unpleasant grainy tasting compounds that can be extracted into the wort.",
    "contributed_by": "Sam Mason <samjbmason>"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Berliner Weisse With Yuzu - B-Sides",
    "tagline": "Japanese Citrus Berliner Weisse.",
    "first_brewed": "11\/2015",
    "description": "Japanese citrus fruit intensifies the sour nature of this German classic.",
    "image_url": "https:\/\/images.punkapi.com\/v2\/keg.png",
    "abv": 4.2,
    "ibu": 8,
    "target_fg": 1007,
    "target_og": 1040,
    "ebc": 8,
    "srm": 4,
    "ph": 3.2,
    "attenuation_level": 83,
    "volume": {
      "value": 20,
      "unit": "liters"
    },
    "boil_volume": {
      "value": 25,
      "unit": "liters"
    },
    "method": {
      "mash_temp": [
        {
          "temp": {
            "value": 60,
            "unit": "celsius"
          },
          "duration": 10
        },
        {
          "temp": {
            "value": 65,
            "unit": "celsius"
          },
          "duration": 30
        },
        {
          "temp": {
            "value": 72,
            "unit": "celsius"
          },
          "duration": 10
        },
        {
          "temp": {
            "value": 78,
            "unit": "celsius"
          },
          "duration": 5
        }
      ],
      "fermentation": {
        "temp": {
          "value": 21,
          "unit": "celsius"
        }
      },
      "twist": "Soured naturally using the kettle souring technique, Yuzu fruit: 50g at middle, Yuzu juice: 200ml at FV"
    },
    "ingredients": {
      "malt": [
        {
          "name": "Propino Pale Malt",
          "amount": {
            "value": 1.63,
            "unit": "kilograms"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Wheat Malt",
          "amount": {
            "value": 1.63,
            "unit": "kilograms"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Propino Pale Malt for kettle 0.03kg souring",
          "amount": {
            "value": 0.03,
            "unit": "kilograms"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Acidulated Malt for kettle souring",
          "amount": {
            "value": 0.03,
            "unit": "kilograms"
          }
        }
      ],
      "hops": [
        {
          "name": "Bramling Cross",
          "amount": {
            "value": 10,
            "unit": "grams"
          },
          "add": "middle",
          "attribute": "bitter"
        }
      ],
      "yeast": "Wyeast 1056 - American Ale\u2122"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend Nil-Coalescing Operator ( ?? ). You can find detailed info [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html)

class Test {
    var ibu: Double?
}

```
var tt: Test? = Test()
tt?.ibu = 3.14
print(String(describing: tt?.ibu)) // Optional("3.14")
print(tt?.ibu ?? 0) // 3.14
tt?.ibu = nil
print(String(describing: tt?.ibu)) // nil
print(tt?.ibu ?? 0) // 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [optional binding](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID333) to avoid this problem

Use

```
if let ibu = item?.ibu {
  labelAmargor.text = "\(String(describing: ibu))" 
}
```

Instead of

```
labelAmargor.text = "\(String(describing: item!.ibu))"
```

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for helping me man! It worked perfectly. However, did you see my Struct? Should I use optionals or remove?

Comment: `if let ibu = item?.ibu {` and don't use String(describing:) method. `labelAmargor.text = "\(ibu)" `

Comment: @TituJow You should use optionals

Comment: So, should I put optionals on all of the properties?

Comment: Thank you so much, @LeoDabus! I appreciate it